# How to display error / result messages to the user upon an action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, message

I've been working for some time on an application and a slight problem arose.

I wonder how I could display error / results to the user upon any action undertaken.

Up to now here's how I proceeded with an example:

```
if(itemID == null)
{
    ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "The ID provided provoked an error. Please try again. If the problem persist, contact your local administrator.";
}
```

Something extremely simple... if we consider that the user remains in the same view. Or there are many places in which I must redict the user using `RedirectToAction("Action")`, and that ViewData is then flushed.

So I am asking any MVC "wise-master" out there: do you have an efficient, re-usable way of displaying messages, may it be in **any** format? And could you explain sommarily how you would do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's an error then, in general, the user *should* stay in the same view and not be redirected.  So they can correct the error and try again.  So you'd basically just do this:

```
if(itemID == null)
{
    ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "The ID provided provoked an error. Please try again. If the problem persist, contact your local administrator.";
    return View(); // you probably have a model to include as well
}
else
{
    // perform your action
    return RedirectToAction("some action");
}
```

After all, just look at the error message you're displaying:

> The ID provided provoked an error. **Please try again.** If the problem persist, contact your local administrator.

You might also consider using something like [`TempData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata.aspx) which doesn't get flushed until it's used.  Perhaps like this:

```
if(itemID == null)
{
    TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "The ID provided provoked an error. Please try again. If the problem persist, contact your local administrator.";
}
```

This will persist across redirects and will be available until after it's requested.  So even if you send the user through some complex series of redirects, when a view eventually renders and checks for a value in `TempData["ErrorMessage"]` it will still be there.  (And I think will be destroyed after it's read.)

Comment: Yeah, in a way, you are right, but as I mentioned there are cases when the user might be redirected upon an error. For example, I ofter display a list of items having an actionlink (ex: remove) linked to each items. So the user might try to remove it, triggering the actionlink. But in the case that the user might not be able to remove the item, I may have to redirect him, and that message is lost.

Comment: Oh, the TempData might be a good idea! So if I replace these lines: `@if (ViewData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
{
    <span class="errorMessage">@ViewData["ErrorMessage"]</span><br/>    
}`
With:
`@if (TempData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
{
    <span class="errorMessage">@TempData["ErrorMessage"]</span><br/>    
}`, would it work?

Comment: @HerveS: It should, unless something else is wrong.  I use the exact same construct in one of my projects.